# XmlDocument.InnerXml is null, but InnerText is not

Tags: .net, xml, xmldocument

I'm using `XmlDocument` and `XmlElement` to build a simple (but large) XML document that looks something like:

```
<Widgets>
    <Widget>
        <Stuff>foo</Stuff>
        <MoreStuff>bar</MoreStuff>...lots more child nodes
    </Widget>
    <Widget>...lots more Widget nodes
</Widgets>
```

My problem is that when I'm done building the XML, the `XmlDocument.InnerXml` is null, but the `InnerText` still shows all the text of all the child nodes.

Has anyone ever seen a problem like this before? What kind of input data would cause these symptoms? I expected the `XmlDocument` to just throw an exception if it was given bad data.

**Note**: I'm pretty sure this is related to the input data as I can only reproduce it against certain data sets. I also tried escaping the data with [SecurityElement.Escape](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securityelement.escape(VS.80).aspx) but it made no difference.

**EDIT**
Here's the code I'm using to build the XML:

```
Private Function BuildXml(widgets as ICollection(Of MyNamespace.Widget)) As String
    Dim xDoc As New XmlDocument
    Dim parentNode As XmlElement = xDoc.CreateElement("Widgets")
    xDoc.AppendChild(parentNode)

    For Each w as Widget in widgets
        Dim widgetNode As XmlElement = xDoc.CreateElement("Widget")
        widgetNode.AppendChild(CreateElement(xDoc, w.Stuff, "Stuff"))
        // lots more...
        parentNode.AppendChild(widgetNode)
    Next

    Return xDoc.OuterXml
End Function

Private Function CreateElement(ByVal xDoc As XmlDocument, ByVal value As String, ByVal elementName As String) As XmlElement
    Dim element As XmlElement = xDoc.CreateElement(elementName)
    element.InnerText = System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape(value)

    Return element
End Function
```

Comment: are you able to save document to a file

Comment: can you provide some of the actual xml building code? does outerXML return null as well?

Comment: @curtisk Added some code to the question above. Yes, the `OuterXml` is also null.

Comment: you can add Assert statement in your CreateElement function to test InnerXml

Comment: Is there a chance you are using strange characters for element names, causing an issue in the XML Document and its set encoding?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried normalizing the XMLDocument after you add all the elements and before trying to read the InnerXml or OuterXML?

Comment: I just ran into the same issue - also normalized the document first but no bingo. XDocument does the right thing though.

Comment: Actually the solution is to use InnerText - Value is not appropriate.